# How might one verify that a file has been copied?

Tags: files, security, timestamps, stat, forensics

Is there a way to make sure that a file has been copied to a USB drive?

(Ex: I have a file secret.db and I suppose that my friend has copied it into his USB drive. With `stat $filename` I cannot see the updated a/c/m/time because `cp` doesn't update the timestamps).

Is there a way to know that or is it impossible?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Bash v4.

Comment: If you have a file that could be copied to a USB drive, it could also be read. If its name is secret.db and it can be read by others, then it is no longer a secret! You should use an cipher container (such as EcryptFS or TrueCrypt) to keep your secret file a secret. Then it will give a hard time to your "friend" to read your secret even if they can get a copy of it!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to ask whether you can tell if somebody made a copy of your file?

Comment: @Huygens yes, in fact i use encfs :) This is only a question that I have asked myself.

Comment: @Wesley yes, this is what i want to do :)

Comment: It's as easy to tell as whether someone has taken a picture of your house.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR: In many cases, you can see whether the file was accessed; however, it is impossible to tell whether a copy was made or not.**

It seems that `atime` [would be updated](https://superuser.com/questions/368137/if-i-cp-a-file-is-the-atime-updated) when using `cp` (unless `noatime` is in effect); however, doing any other read operation (like `grep somestring $filename`) would also touch the file.

In most installs (without a ton of auditing), it is not possible to find out *why* exactly the file was read, and whether the process reading the file also wrote a copy of the data elsewhere (to USB? to socket? to RAM?).

Moreover, this only concerns online, unprivileged attacks. If I have physical access, I could reboot into a live-CD distro, mount the partition read only, copy *anything* off it (or even make a full-disk image) and there would be no marks on the partition (except the incremented mount counter).

Comment: I've done some testing and the "cp" command doesn't update the a/c/m/time :(

Comment: A copy shouldn't modify *create* or *modify* times, that's expected behavior. As for *access* time: is the partition mounted with `noatime` or `relatime` option? That would give the results you describe. (IIRC, many distros mount `ext` partitions with `relatime` by default)

Comment: My home partition is mounted as: `UUID=675e8177-c75b-402d-aaea-c0e5ee929a28 /home           ext4    defaults,user_xattr        0       2`

Comment: Quoth `man mount`: "relatime
              Update inode access times relative to modify or change time.  Access time is only updated if the previous access time was earlier than the current modify or change time.
              Since Linux 2.6.30, the kernel defaults to the behavior provided by this option (unless noatime was  specified), and the strictatime option is required to obtain traditional semantics. In addition, since Linux 2.6.30,
              the file's last access time is always  updated  if  it  is more than 1 day old."
 That's your `defaults` at work, right there.

Comment: Aaaah ok! I've understand! Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: Good answer to include mounting the drive as read-only. Seems like you are out of luck @polslinux. Best to secure your files with encrypted containers in this case, matey :-) [more info](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/11162/howto-encrypted-home-partition)

Comment: @Wesley ahaha yes yes in fact i use gpg ;) it's just a personal curiosity. :D

Comment: Nothing bad with a dose of curiosity mixed with paranoia ;) My `/home` and `swap` are LUKS encrypted, [steps posted here](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/11162/howto-encrypted-home-partition/). On my little [netbook](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/U100-Plus.html#/?div=Specification) I don't even notice performance hits. Just FYI :)

Answer (score -1):

I solve it using python script, the idea is checking in a loop if file size is incrementing, you have to set time.sleep for your needs, in my case was only 0.05s to see if file is increasing his size...
The check ends when size in the before size check iteration is the same in the actual size check...

dict is a dictionary type, initialize it with 'dict = {}'

```
               if not filename in dict:
                #new item...
                time.sleep(0.05)
                dict = {filename: os.stat(fullInFilename).st_size}
                break #next iteration loop, that finds itself again
            else:  # already exists in dict, copying finished?
                time.sleep(0.05)
                sizeRegistrado = dict[filename]
                sizeActual = os.stat(fullInFilename).st_size

                if sizeActual != sizeRegistrado:
                    # still copying...
                    dict[filename] = sizeActual
                    print(sizeActual)
                    break
                else:
                    # Done copying
                    #print("pop!")
                    dict.pop(filename)
```

Comment: The question was how to determine if a file has been read. You are trying to detect changes to a file (write access) IIUC.